# Missing required parameters for [Route: proforms.edit] [URI: proforms/{proform}/edit]

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, web-frameworks

I think that i am sending all important variables to view, but no. I don't know why I am getting this error:  Missing required parameters for [Route: proforms.edit] [URI: proforms/{proform}/edit].
On this line of code: `return redirect()->route('proforms.edit', compact('proform', 'query'))`

This is controller method for this:

```
  public function destroy2(Proform $proform, $query2)
        {
          $query = DB::table('dynamic_fields')
          ->join('proforms', 'dynamic_fields.proform_id', '=', 'proforms.id')
          ->select('dynamic_fields.*','proforms.*')
          ->where('proform_id', '=', $proform->id)
          ->get();  
        
          DB::table('dynamic_fields')->where('id_pozycji', '=', '$query2')->delete();
        
        
        return redirect()->route('proforms.edit', compact('proform', 'query'))
        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
        }
        }
```

This is all code for view proforms.edit whitch generates that error.

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Edytuj produkt</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('proforms.index') }}"> Wstecz</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif


    <form action="{{ route('proforms.update',$proform->id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')


         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Data wystawienia:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="proformdate" value="{{ $proform->proformdate }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Data wystawienia">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Kontrahent:</strong>
                                        <br>
                    <select class="form-controll" name="user_id">
                            @foreach($users as $user)
                            <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->showname}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Waluta:</strong>
                                        <br>
                    <select class="form-controll" name="currency_id">
                            @foreach($currencys as $currency)
                            <option value="{{$currency->id}}">{{$currency->currency}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Forma płatności:</strong>
                                        <br>
                    <select class="form-controll" name="form_id">
                            @foreach($forms as $form)
                            <option value="{{$form->id}}">{{$form->form}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Data sprzedaży:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="selldate" value="{{ $proform->selldate }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Termin płatności:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="paymentdate" value="{{ $proform->paymentdate }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Termin płatności">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Forma płatności:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="paymentmethod" value="{{ $proform->paymentmethod }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Miejsce wystawienia:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="city" value="{{ $proform->city }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Status:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="status" value="{{ $proform->status }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Uwagi:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $proform->comments }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Uwagi">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left" style="margin: 35px;">
                <h3>Pozycje faktury</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Nazwa towaru lub usługi:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $proform->name }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Data wystawienia">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>PKWiU:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="PKWIU" value="{{ $proform->PKWIU }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Kontrahent">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Ilość:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="{{ $proform->quantity }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Jednostka:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="unit" value="{{ $proform->unit }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Termin płatności">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Cena netto jednostki:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="netunit" value="{{ $proform->netunit }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Netto razem:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="nettotal" value="{{ $proform->nettotal }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Stawka VAT:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="VATrate" value="{{ $proform->VATrate }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Brutto jednostka:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="grossunit" value="{{ $proform->grossunit }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Brutto razem:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="grosstotal" value="{{ $proform->grosstotal }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Zapisz</button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>

  
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>

            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('id', 'Numer')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('name', 'Nazwa pozycji')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('PKWIU', 'PKWiU')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('quanity', 'Ilość')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('unit', 'Jednostka')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('netunit', 'Jednostka netto')</th> 
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('nettotal', 'Razem netto')</th> 
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('VATrate', 'Stawka VAT')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('grossunit', 'Brutto jednostka')</th> 
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('grosstotal', 'Brutto razem')</th>  
            <th width="280px">Akcja</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($query as $query2)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $query2->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $query2->PKWIU }}</td>
            <td>{{ $query2->quantity }}</td>
            <td>{{ $query2->unit }}</td>
            <td>{{ $query2->netunit }}</td>
            <td>{{ $query2->nettotal }}</td>
            <td>{{ $query2->VATrate }}</td>
            <td>{{ $query2->grossunit }}</td>
            <td>{{ $query2->grosstotal }}</td>
           
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('proforms2.destroy2',$query2->id_pozycji) }}" method="GET">
                    
                    @can('product-edit')
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('proforms.edit',$query2->id_pozycji) }}">Edytu</a>
                    @endcan


                    @csrf
                    @method('GET')
                    @can('product-delete')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Usuń</button>
                    @endcan
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>

 

<p class="text-center text-primary"><small>ARTplus 2020</small></p>
@endsection
```

This is route for this view and controller:

```
Route::get('delete/proforms/{query2}','ProformController@destroy2')->name('proforms2.destroy2');
```

Comment: you need to pass the id parameter  with this route `proforms.edit'`  but i think you just deleted this id, so if you pass the id parameter then it wont work,, so redirect to another route like `return redirect()->route('proforms', compact('proform', 'query')`

Comment: i didn't deleted id. $proforom->id is not sending from view to this controller. In $proform i have got only empty array with column names.  But when i add $proform to route I am getting error 404.

Answer (score 1):

your error says that:

Missing required parameters for [Route: proforms.edit] [URI:proforms/{proform}/edit].

note that you should pass `proform` to the route redirector

so you should change

```php
return redirect()->route('proforms.edit', compact('proform', 'query'))
        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
```

to

```php
return redirect()->route('proforms.edit', // [$id] or $id )
        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
```

Comment: Something like that? It dosen't work for me.  
return redirect()->route('proforms.edit', compact('proform', 'query', 'proform->id'))
->with('success','Product deleted successfully');

Comment: no something  like ```eturn redirect()->route('proforms.edit',$proform->id )
        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');```, forget about compact in redirecting to a route

Comment: this wont work, because they just deleted this `$id`

Comment: then you couldn't redirect to edit route, it's better to redirect to index route

Comment: It didnt work. But i checked $proform array and it has not values in it, only has got column names. Why it is not sneding. I deleted only values from query , not proform id. But why proform id is not sending from view. My route looks like that but if i add proform to it , than it returns error 404 page not found.
Route::get('delete/proforms/{query2}','ProformController@destroy2')->name('proforms2.destroy2');

Comment: after deleting your proforms instance, you don't have id of that instance, then you should redirect to a route that doesn't require instance id, like index route, so return redirect()->route('proforms.index') might be a better redirect. for further example look at my and sta conversation.

Comment: I am not deleting proform instance, I am deleting positions from other table dynamic_fields.

Comment: but view sends only empty array for $proform to function destroy2.

Comment: your blade code is ```<form action="{{ route('proforms2.destroy2',$query2->id_pozycji) }}" method="GET"> ``` and you pass id_pozycji, it's obvious that it's empty, and for delete method, you should use GET method

Comment: i changed it to this, but it didn't helped "<form action="{{ route('proforms2.destroy2',$query2->id_pozycji, $proform->id) }}" method="GET">"  

I tried to add $proform in route but it generates error

Comment: change it to something like this ```<form action="{{ route('proforms2.destroy2',[$proform, $query2]) }}" method="GET">```

Comment: Changed and it not helped.

Comment: After this <form action="{{ route('proforms2.destroy2',[$proform, $query2]) }}" method="GET">

 I have got error
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use **compact** method to pass parameters because it usually use for passing data to views so you should write something like that:

```
return redirect()->route('proforms.edit',[$proform,$query])
```

Comment: The problem is that view is sending to this controller empty array $proform. It has only column names. I have to send to this controller  id for $proforom and it will be okay. But how to do this.

Comment: actually your error saying missing required parameter which means you are passing wrong number of parameters. either you are passing one parameter and it recieves 2 parameters

Answer (score 0):

You name route `proforms.edit` the `id` parameter is required, so you need to pass the paremeter.
The shortcut way is :

```
 return redirect()->back()->with('proform', $proform)->with('query', $query)
        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
```

Another way is, pass the parameter as hidden field.
On your blade, add this *input* field into your `form` element :

```
<input type="hidden" name="proform_id" value="{{ $proform->id }}">
```

Then your controller code will be like :

```
return redirect()->route('proforms.edit', $request->proform_id)
  ->with('proform', $proform)
  ->with('query', $query)
  ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
```

Answer (score -1):

you should pass perform name into every route has perform like this example :

```
   <form action="{{ route('proforms.update',['proform'=>$proform->id)] }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
```